# Why onference_auto_outcall_flags doesn't work

Tags: freeswitch

I have the following configuration in my dialplan:

```
<extension name="conference_set_auto_outcall">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^ds_(.*);(.*);(.*);(.*)$">
<action application="answer"/>
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_flags=mute"/>
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_caller_id_name=$${effective_caller_id_name}"/>
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_caller_id_number=$${effective_caller_id_number}"/>
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_profile=default"/>
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_prefix={sip_auto_answer=true,execute_on_answer_1='start_dtmf_generate',execute_on_answer_2='send_dtmf $4'}"/>
<action application="conference_set_auto_outcall" data="{ignore_early_media=true}sofia/gateway/$2/$3"/>
<action application="conference" data="$1+flags{moderator|mute}"/>
</condition>
</extension>
```

I need to set flags to the members that are joined to the conference by the auto call. Unfortunately none of the flags I set in conference_auto_outcall_flags is propagated to the members. I can hear the called member and

```
show channels
```

in fs_cli shows the following information among other staff:

```
1946@default+flags{}
```

e.g. flags aren't assigned.

FreeSwitch version 1.6.6
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeSWITCH wiki seems to be outdated. In 1.6.6 source codes the parameter is called

```
conference_utils_auto_outcall_flags
```

so the flags need to be specified as

```
<action application="set" data="conference_utils_auto_outcall_flags=mute"/>
```